# Opening default google maps crashing program in all API's except 8

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The following code I use in an on click listener for a button and it works great in API8, now that I am checking compatibility its crashing everywhere else. What am I doing wrong?

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The emulator used with the AVD manager must be the google API version not the android version. The latter does not have the maps app installed.